# Survival, Descriptive, and Group Comparisons (>2 groups)

Tags: survival, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, fishers-exact-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I am performing a survival analysis with three cohorts. In the descriptive analysis, I have used Fisher and chi-squared tests to compare the categorical variables (such as sex), and the Kruskal-Wallis test for continuous variables (such as age), under the non-normality assumption. Is it correct? In cases where the difference is significant, do I need to compare groups pairwise?

Thank you very much :)